# SQL Server Agent - to update SQL table from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc, sql-server-agent

this is a newbie questions...
is it possible to write a job that will update my sql (SQL Server 2008) table nightly - from an oracle db? i can't seem to find any tutorials online. please help.

i have already created a ODBC connection in the Data Source Administrator....

Answer (score 2):

You could setup your Oracle database as a [Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) and then create a SSIS package that performs the update. This SSIS package could run on a schedule (Job).